# phonetic algorithms for words that aren't surnames?

Tags: algorithms, string-matching, linguistics

I've been doing a little research into algorithms for matching spelling mistakes in names.  From Soundex through to metaphone and Beider-Morse.  All of these algorithms generally focus on last names with an ever widening language ability (beider-morse being the most useful across a lot of different languages).

I'm wondering if there are any algorithms out there that focus on words that aren't just surnames.  Company names for instance... Norton Rose,  Freshfields Bruckhaus Deringer etc etc

One of the problems with many of the available phonetic algorithms is that they will strip numbers out.  In Surnames/names this is probably a good idea, and few names will really contain numbers... however company names might contain numbers and those might be important to the company, so stripping them out would be detrimental to the search ability.

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat I did wonder if this might come under that... but i don't believe there to be a wide range of algorithms focussing on word groupings that aren't surnames, so figured this was perhaps quite unique rather than what language in a sea of languages should i use for this trivial thing... i'm willing to accept that perhaps i am wrong in this instance

Comment: I don't find any distinction between surnames and company names.  Is there some characteristic about people's names that somehow makes them tractable to a unique algorithm?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've been using this site http://yomguithereal.github.io/talisman/phonetics/#algorithms just as a playground... but try something like: The Ledbury vs Ledbury against Kathrine vs Cathrin

Comment: There's nothing special about such an algorithm.  It has a list of common people names to compare against.  Probably it uses something like Levenshtein distance to see if the name is close to a well-known person name.  And it's prone to failure; young people change name spelling all the time to be cool, so Kathrine can be a false negative.

Comment: Anyway, you can do the same with company names.  Just provide your algorithm with a well-known company list.

Comment: With the greatest respect @RobertHarvey, i'm not 100% sure you understand the soundex algorithm (and associated algorithms, check Beider Morse source for fun)... it's not comparing against well known names, it's working out phonetic pronunciation based on a set of rules.  Most of these algo's strip numbers out, which in company names, might be important.

Comment: @Jared: Slow your roll, Charlie.  That's why I was asking.  I am aware of Soundex, and I know how it works.  My question is still the same: why couldn't you also do that with company names?

Comment: Regarding your edit: if it's an open-source algorithm, couldn't you just modify it so that it doesn't strip out the numbers?  Also, does Soundex recognize numbers?

Comment: @RobertHarvey apologies, I didn't mean to sound rude.  I could possibly edit the algorithms not to strip numbers and other characters that might be important to a company name, but really I'd be getting into territory where I don't really know what i'm doing and might lead to unknown consequences.  The algo's aren't built for *1* and *one* being the same like Kathrine and Cathrin are the same